# How to include a method in a string.format syntax inside a console.writeline in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a method that displays something like:

```
public void display(){

Console.Writeline("Message");
}
```

And I should include it in the console.writeline that use string.format (the one inside `<<>>` is just how should it look:

```
int CodeName = 52;
Console.WriteLine("Mutant Name: {0} ------ Message: {1}", CodeName, <<dispplay()>>);
```

Comment: You simply can't. Have your method return a string instead

Comment: Console.WriteLine($"Mutant Name: {CodeName} ------ Message: {display()}");

Comment: @Gururaj -- First of all, that assumes C# 6 and also what is `display`?

Comment: @rory.ap - I'm making an assumption that emjtv is using latest C# edition.

Comment: @Gururaj -- But the OP didn't' say that, and you didn't make that clear in your comment.  Also, where is `display` coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Try calling the `display` method by making it **return** a value.

Like this:

```
public string display() 
{
    return "Message";
}

int CodeName = 52;

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Mutant Name: {0} ------ Message: {1}", CodeName, display()));
```

Comment: can also simplify to `Console.WriteLine("Mutant Name: {0} ------ Message: {1}", CodeName, display());`

Comment: Thanks @AlexK., old habits die hard. Updated the answer.